# Classical proof that well-ordering principle is equivalent to complete induction

Tags: proof-writing, induction

I want to prove that:

Well ordering principle ⟺ Complete Induction.

I am interested in both directions of the implication. That is, that if every non-empty set contains a least element then if a property P holds for all naturals less than n-1 it must hold for n. And viceversa.

I want the proof to be classical (I suspect this is quite difficult to prove constructively)

Comment: I see, didn't realize this is being asked for. The proof by contradiction seems to be quite simple though, any reason why seeking "non contradiction" proof?

Comment: Wait, now I'm confused. I thought "classical" refers to "classical logic" - thus including tertium non datur.

Comment: @Sil Simply for the interest of an intuitionistc proof. Which is what the OP seems to be looking for. The proof in the link you suggested was classical.   The OP is using contradictory concepts in his question.

Comment: @Stefan I made a mistake, I meant intuitionistic instead of classical.